# Backup SQL server to Rackspace Cloud Files

Tags: sql-server-2008, rackspace-cloud

What is the best way to take daily or hourly backups from SQL and then have them automatically upload to Racksapce Cloud Files.

Answer (score 0):

You could do daily full backups and periodic differential backups, but you may want to look at using transaction log backups instead, assuming your database is using FULL recovery mode. With log backups you could send a full backup once a day or week, then send log backups every hour. Each time you send a new full backup, you could delete all the older log backups.  As long as you have a full backup and ALL the logs, you can restore the data up to the point of the last log; you would basically be doing log shipping without applying the logs.

You'll also need to decide how to get the files there, rsync/robocopy/other, and make sure you have the bandwidth to keep up with the transfers. And make sure you have some notification process if it fails.

If you're looking for disaster recovery, remember to focus on the the plan to restore more than the plan to backup. Estimating the time requirements and documenting the process to restore needs to be done and practiced before a disaster, not during.